# No mostrar controles al identificar que la pagina !IsPostBack en c#

Tags: c#

Requiero ocultar los controles de un formulario que pretendo utilizar para crear solicitudes de crédito.

el procedimiento a realizar es: Si la página se muestra por primera vez se muestran los controles para añadir información del cliente y de codeudor, se almacenada al editar se deben mostrar los controles de acuerdos de pago y fecha inicial.

lo intente hacer de la siguiente manera:

Declaro el metodo

```
public void deshabilitarcontroles(){
    TextBoxValor_Credito.Visible = false;
    DropDownListPeriodo_cre.Visible = false;
    TextBoxCuotas.Visible = false;
    TextBoxFechainicial1.Visible = false;
    TextBoxFechainicial2.Visible = false;
    TextBoxValorcuotainicial1.Visible = false;
    TextBoxValorcuotainicial2.Visible = false;
}

if (!IsPostBack) { 
    deshabilitarcontroles();
}
```

Pero veo que me deshabilita solo los campos para almacenar los datos, no me deshabilita la caja de texto completa.

¿Cómo podría hacerlo?
asi me aparece

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

si la pagina es por primera no deberian aparecer

De antemano gracias, saludos!

Comment: A que te refieres con caja de texto completa?

Comment: Toda la linea, es decir si tenemos el campo *periodo* que no se muestre ni el texto ni el campo para almacenar el valor

Comment: y pero no estas ocultando los label por ningun lado.. son dos componentes distintos...

Comment: Eso es exactamente lo que quiero saber, como lo hago o que debo hacer, soy novato en c#

Comment: mete todo en un panel, y en lugar de ocultar objeto por objeto oculta el panel

Comment: dentro de una tabla no me deja añadir un panel

Comment: Te refieres a los labels ? 
tambien tienes que hacer que los labels sean invisibles, comparte tu codigo asp para ver cual es el problema

Comment: Hola, ya he logrado solucionarlo.

Comment: Serás el héroe de muchos usuarios que pasen por lo mismo, coloca la respuesta :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fue sencillo,lo que puede hacer para ocultar la fila completa fue añadir un ID al `<tr>`  es decir:

```
<tr id="nivel2">
  ...//Estructura
<tr>
```

y en el método indicar que ese control sea visible o oculto respecto a ese id

```
public void deshabilitarcontroles(){
   nivel2.Visible = false;
}
```

y aplique la condición tal y como la tenia

```
if (!IsPostBack) { 
    deshabilitarcontroles();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Lo que puedes hacer para colocar bloquear o poner invisible .
Lo que realizo agregar un void que me va ingresar un Bool si es true es decir que va aparecer y si es false que todo lo que esta no se vera.

Espero haberte ayudado.

```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    if (!IsPostBack)
                { 
                 visible(false)
                 }
    }


     void visible(Boolean blo)
            {
    TextBoxValor_Credito.Visible = blo;
                DropDownListPeriodo_cre.Visible = blo;
                TextBoxCuotas.Visible = blo;
                TextBoxFechainicial1.Visible = blo;
                TextBoxFechainicial2.Visible = blo;
                TextBoxValorcuotainicial1.Visible = blo;
                TextBoxValorcuotainicial2.Visible = blo;


    }
```